# Invoking a private method having a Class<T> typed parameter via reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method as follows:

```
private <T> T _findEntity(Class<T> klass, Object entityId) {
    ...
}
```

To invoke this function via reflection, I have tried the below snippet with an unsuccessful result:

```
Method method = GenericPersistenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("_findEntity", Object.class, Object.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
Player player = (Player) method.invoke(genericPersistenceManager, Player.class, "str");
```

So is there a way to call a method like `_findEntity` via Java reflection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for wrong method. Your method takes two arguments of type - `Class` and `Object`. And you are searching for method which takes `Object` as both the arguments.

You should change your 2nd argument to `Class.class`:

```
Method method = GenericPersistenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("_findEntity", 
                                                     Class.class, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your call to

```
Method method = GenericPersistenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("_findEntity", Class.class, Object.class);
```